# Binding not updated when using IOC

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml, template10

I've never used *IOC* in any of my apps, and today I decided to learn how to use it but I'm having some issues with bindings.

What happens is that bound values are updated as soon as the page shows, but changing some of them later doesn't reflect to the page.

Here are some snippets of the part that's causing issues:

*service*

```
public class TimerService : BindableBase, ITimerService
{
    public TimerService()
    {   
        RemainingTime = UpdateInterval;
        var updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };            
        updateTimer.Tick += UpdateTimerOnTick;
        updateTimer.Start();
    }        

    private double _remainingTime;

    public int UpdateInterval { get; set; } = 90;

    public double RemainingTime
    {
        get { return _remainingTime; }
        set { 
            // From Template10, it calls RaisePropertyChanged (and even calling it manually doesn't help)
            Set(ref _remainingTime, value); 
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTimerOnTick(object sender, object o)
    {
        RemainingTime -= 1;
        if (Math.Abs(RemainingTime) < 0.05) RemainingTime = UpdateInterval;
        // Timer is running fine as I can see the prints
        Debug.WriteLine($"{RemainingTime}");            
    }
}
```

*locator*

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ITimerService, DesignTimeTimerService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ITimerService, TimerService>(true);
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainPageViewModel>();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();
}
```

*viewModel*

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ITimerService TimerService { get; }

    public MainPageViewModel(ITimerService timerService)
    {
        TimerService = timerService;
    }

}
```

*page*

```
<Page x:Class="Views.MainPage"
      ...
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=MainPageViewModel}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

      ...

      <ProgressBar Maximum="{x:Bind ViewModel.TimerService.UpdateInterval}"
                   ...
                   Value="{x:Bind ViewModel.TimerService.RemainingTime, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource EmptyConverter}}" />


      ...

      (.cs file)

      private MainPageViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as MainPageViewModel;
```

What I'd expect is to have `ProgressBar`'s value decreasing as the timer goes, but it just stays still on the very first value that I set.

I've also tried adding an empty converter to see if something happens but it's like `ProgressBar` never receives the update event.

Do you have any hints on this?

Comment: Your setup looks fine to me. I've had some issues in the past with the `ProgressBar` tough, changes in the `Value` property would only show up if the binding `Mode` was set to `TwoWays`. I cannot reproduce this behaviour right now, but its worth a shot. You may also want to bind to a `Textblock.Text` or something similar to verify its not a problem with the `ProgressBar`.

Comment: I've just finished doing some tests: `TwoWay` doesn't help, but guess what? Replacing `x:Bind` with `Binding` solved it. I guess where we shoud use `x:Bind` since it always fails. EDIT: not posting this as answer yet because I'd like to know if someone is able to make this work with `x:Bind`.

Comment: Could you please provide the reproduce project? Upload to github or somewhere.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT stripped down repro [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wm8hgso25wr7asv/TimerIocRepro.zip?dl=0)